# How do I sync word to audio?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

How do I sync word to audio in Adobe Acrobat DC?

**This** is a pen.

This **is** a pen.

This is **a** pen.

This is a **pen**.

For the example, the text will became bold or change to red colour if the audio is reading the word.

Comment: I don't think Acrobat has built in tools to detect which word is being sounded in the audio. I'm sure there are tools out there (try "karaoke lyric tool") but I highly doubt that Acrobat can do it.

Comment: I have to say this is pretty darn ***far*** *outside* our usual **G**raphic **D**esign **S**tack **E**xchange question scope... you are asking how to *synchronously dynamically highlight* each specific word that is being processed and audio output by a text-to-voice routine which is ***outside*** Adobe Acrobat - in the OS or a separate helper app... this is pretty high-level coding, and has significant security implications as well as Intellectual Property implications; I think this should be migrated to SO or another coding-specific area.